# How do you get a data section from a Linked list to compare?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have just started learning linked list and was messing around with it but then I ran into a problem. I was not sure how to access the data member to actually compare it. In my code, I prompt the user to input grades and when they input -1 then it signals that they are finished. My first thought was to get the pointer pointing to the node to get the data like I did in scanf, however I can't compare pointers to integers. Is there a way to get data members from linked lists to compare? Also, pointing out other errors would be appreciated as well because I don't know linked lists too well. I have the following code:

```
int main() {
    struct Node
    {
        int grade;
        struct Node *next;
    };

    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *first;
    struct Node *temp = 0;
    first = 0;

    while (****** != -1) {       //This is what I need the data from linked list for
        head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        printf("Enter the grade: \n ");
        scanf("%d", &head -> grade);
        if (first != 0) {
            temp -> next = head;
            temp = head;
        }
        else
        {
            first = temp = head;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sky, when learning linked-lists (or just about any other complex structure), pull out an 8.5x11 sheet of paper, a pencil, and draw your nodes and node-pointers linking them together. Take a small example, 4-5 nodes and then work out you `add`, `del`, `find`, etc.. functions using the paper for your reference to get the links and loops correct. It takes far less time than endlessly looking at the screen hoping for inspiration `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a number of issue with your code:

1) Don't scan directly into the list - use a temp variable

2) Always check return values

3) Make sure to initialize variables, i.e. head

Try something like:

```
struct Node
{
    int grade;
    struct Node *next;
};

int main() {

    struct Node *head = NULL;
    struct Node *temp;
    int data;

    while (1) 
    {
        printf("Enter the grade: \n ");
        if (scanf("%d", &data) != 1)
        {
            // Illegal input
            exit(1);
        }
        if (data == -1) break;  // Stop the loop

        temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);  // Allocate new element
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            // Out of mem
            exit(1);
        }
        temp -> next = head;   // Insert new element in the front of list
        temp -> grade = data;
        head = temp;           // Move the front (aka head) to the new element
    }

    // .... add code that uses the list

    return 0;
}
```